# Swagger Java: Add custom servlet without JAXRS annotations

Tags: java, swagger, odata, swagger-2.0

I have an application that is using JAX-RS (and swagger) annotations heavily and all is shown nicely in the swagger definition.

However one servlet implements a customer restful interface (oData, Apache oLingo) and this is not using any of the JAX-RS annotations. Yet I would like to document it.

To make it as simple as possible, let's say I have a class

```
@WebServlet("/rest1")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print("{ \"text\": \"Hello World\" }");
    }
}
```

I would like that servlet to show up in the swagger output as well without losing the JAX-RS entities.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Extensions?source=post_page-----a56d1719c9a3----------------------) I would think I need to extend the reader to output this servlet as well and a custom ModelConverter?? to add hardcoded properties. But even if that is correct, I can't find a good starting point. Not to mention that I hope there is a simpler, more direct, way. Samples of swagger have been of no help either.

Comment: or you could rewrite the endpoint :-)

Comment: @Ivonet What do you mean by that? Adding JAX-RS annotations to the oLingo project? Well yes, that would be the perfect solution because then I don't have to do anything. Obviously I am asking my question because that is not the case. https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/230

Comment: Sorry about my flippancy. I was reading your example and it seemed to easy to talk about and just rewriting it seemed a lot easier than making a custom something.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately I even tried enhancing oLingo. Way too large of a project. And the request I linked is from 2014, hence my hopes are low it will be done anytime soon.